# Word Add-in - find if dialog has focus?

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I am writing a word add-in in VB .NET (using Add-in Express, but I don't think that's relevant).
I have created shortcuts, but I only want them to take effect if the document itself is in focus, not a dialog - for example, "Find and replace" or any other.

How do I determine if a dialog has focus?
The "Selection" property of the application points to the selection in the document, even if a dialog is currently selected. I can't find any "HasFocus"-equivalent property anywhere either. I'm running out of ideas :o)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me:

My add-in keeps a reference to the handle of the most recently activated Word window, by using the GetActiveWindow API during the WindowActivate event of the Word application. This is necessary since, up until Office 2013, the Window object does not expose a handle property.
When a shortcut is triggered, I compare that to the handle of the currently active window, using the same API. If they don't match, I simply don't proceed :o)